# Android: DataOutputStream doesn't throw Exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have a server that accept more then one Client. Every Client is stored inside an ArrayList of Sockets. If a Client, for some reason, disconnects from my server, this should understand which client has been disconnected, close the client and delete it from the List. 
Reading other question here I have understood that the only way to understand which client is disconnected is this: try to send data through all socket connected and the first one which throws Exception has to be closed.

The problem is that if the client is a simple Java-Application it works perfectly. But when the Client is an Android-Application, the data is sent through the (supposed) disconnected Socket. In this way my Server's algorithm doesn't throw Exceptions and it keeps sending data to all Sockets Causing a disaster. The code of clients (java and android) is Exactly the same but the results are different:

Server Code:

```
List<Socket> sList = new ArrayList<>();
Socket s;
int i = 0;
int whichSocket;

try
 {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
        while (true) 
          {
            System.out.println("Server is Listening");
            s = ss.accept();
            sList.add(s);               
            System.out.println("Server Accepted Client --- " +s.toString());
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                  public void run() {
                    try 
                       {
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  

                        while (true) 
                        {
                         // For every message received from one client, it iterate through list sending that dat to ALL CLIENTS in the list of Socket
                            String test = dis.readUTF();
                            System.out.println("Message Sent By -- " + s.toString());
                            System.out.println(test);

                            while(i < sList.size()){
                                 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sList.get(i).getOutputStream());
                                 dos.writeUTF(test);    
                                 System.out.println("Messaggio Sent To -- " + sList.get(i).toString());
                                 dos.flush();
                                 ++i;
                             }
                            i=0;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("First Exception");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally
                    {
                        try
                        {   
                         // An exception has been thrown. This means that one client is disconnected.Which One? Let's send data to all Clients in the list.                                             
                             whichSocket = -1;
                            for(Socket temp : sList)
                              {
                                                                                       System.out.println("PENEEEE inviato a -- " + temp.toString());
                                whichSocket ++;
                                DataOutputStream dosser = new DataOutputStream(temp.getOutputStream());                                 
                                dosser.write(1);
                                System.out.println("Message Sent To -- " + temp.toString());
                                dosser.flush();
                            }                                  
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {         
                            System.out.println("Second Exception");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally
                            {
                            try 
                             {                  
                                sList.get(whichSocket).close();
                                System.out.println("Socket Closed --- " + sList.get(whichSocket).toString());
                                sList.remove(whichSocket);                  
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Third Exception");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            t2.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("General Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client Code:

```
        while(flag) {
          if(!isConnected) {
              try {         
                 s = new Socket("192.168.1.69", 7000);
                  isConnected = true;
                  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                  while (flag) {
                      String result = dis.readUTF();
                      Log.d("InputStreammmm", result);
                   }
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.d("THIS IS", "THE EXCEPTIONN");
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } finally {
                  isConnected = false;
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Causing what disaster?

Comment: Pratically it disconnect all Clients from the last one which has been connectes to the one that effectively throws the exception. Pratically the server close the connection starting from the last one untill the exception is not thrown anymore. And if I have this situation for example: First Socket Connected = AndroidApp, Second Socket Connected JavaApp... If I close the connection of android app.. my server close the JavaApp first and then the Android App